# Make button turns background white when press

Tags: button, windows-phone-8

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-bQZRfy4g4t0/TWK05e_Bx9I/AAAAAAAAAEY/nym2bRu-RjI/s1600/5.bmp

How do I make my button that contains image change to white background when being press?

On default, when I press my button it doesn't show the image in the button and change to phone accent color.

Here's the XAML code for the button :

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="Img">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Assets/appbar.control.play.png" />  
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is create a button template that modifies the pressed visual state.

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483278/remove-button-highlight-on-press-in-silverlight) SO answers helps you, both links have the Pressed visual state code.

Comment: I added my button's Pressed visual state code, could you clarify which code I have to modify? I didn't understand at all the answers in the links

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the Pressed visual state to:

(In this case background is changed to Red when the button is pressed)

```
    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="Img">
              //Set you image path like this
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Assets/..." />                                                                                  
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>  
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
```

Comment: you could set value property according to your need...like above

Comment: OK, I got the button to turn white when pressed, but how do I make the image inside the button to turn to black?

Comment: Ok..updated code above with image path...it could help your's problem

Comment: Still doesn't work, the button turns white without highlighting the image in it to black. Code updated